# How to get Linear gradient effect on mozilla firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am using the following css to get the linear gradient effect, But its not working in mozilla firefox, Can anyone of you know it pls help to get the same effect in firefox also.
**The css is**

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0,transparent);
```

Comment: `-webkit-` means it is targeted to webkit browsers. (At least it used to be that way. Seems to change nowadays.)

Comment: @Sirko: `-webkit-` (and other similar prefixes) actually means it's an experimental feature, which has been added to the Webkit engine but isn't standardised yet. In fact, gradients *have* been standardised now and newer browsers don't need the prefix, so you should be able to drop the prefixes for this feature it in most cases, unless you need to support older browser versions.

Comment: @Spudley I'm well aware of all the stuff you mention. But the key fact is, that those experimental features are (most of the time) restricted to one specific engine. In consequence they fail on any other engine, like it happened with ops code. If the feature is supported at all most likely the engine will either use the prefix-less version or use its own prefix instead.

Comment: @Sirko: fair enough if you know all that. :) The bit you put in brackets seemed to imply you weren't sure.

Comment: @Spudley The comment in brackets should take care of the discussion, to implement `-webit-` features using that prefix in other browsers. I'm actually not aware, if that was pushed through or not.

Comment: @Sirko: No, that was a while ago, and it never really happened. Opera *did* imlepement a few of the common ones, but then they converted to using the Webkit engine anyway. None of the others did it at all. And now that Chrome has split away from Webkit and is no longer using prefixes for new experimental features (they're hiding them behind developer config settings instead), the concept of prefixes has become much less of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) editor for gradients. A nice visual editor for gradients with css code output. The created code supports every major browser and provides a fallback for older Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Use -moz-linear-gradient:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65) 0,transparent);
```

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afG4V/)</kbd>

And the W3C version with a slightly different syntax:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65) 0, transparent);
```

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afG4V/1/)</kbd>

You should always use vendor specific prefixes (-o, -moz, and so on) before the W3C one. To prevent writing them by yourself, you can use a ***compile-time prefixer***, like [Nettus+ Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/), or a ***real-time prefixer***, like [Lea Verou's Prefix free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

In the specific case of Gradients, you can use this great [Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) that prefixes them for you.

Comment: The `-moz-` prefix hasn't been required for gradients since Firefox 15. You don't need it.

Comment: Of course, but he has to change the code (`to top` instead of `bottom`). With its current code, it only works with -moz- prefix: http://jsfiddle.net/afG4V/1/ Using a prefixer or the generator gives him the right code for each browser, he should support previous versions too. I was not suggesting to use the -moz- prefix only, but thanks for pointing it out, maybe I was not clear enough, I'll edit it now.

Comment: fair enough, but all the same you should not be using the `-moz-` prefix for this feature. Once a feature has become standardised, browsers are supposed to drop support for the old prefixed versions, so if you've used the `-moz-` version it will stop working in a future version of Firefox when they drop support for it. Better to just use the standard syntax now, since it's already there.

Comment: Spudley, I figured out that it was definitely not clear: due to rush-writing I forgot the "before the W3C one" part, that was definitely intended while writing the answer. I always use only W3C declarations, letting PrefixFree prefixing them on the fly. Thanks again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #000, #fff);` 
That's the format.

Comment: The `-moz-` prefix hasn't been required since Firefox 15. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when using *any* CSS feature with a prefix like `-webkit-`, you should *always* also specify the same feature without the prefixed as well.

The prefix indicates that it is (or was) an experimental feature which a particular browser supports, but which may still be in development or may not be standardised yet.

When a feature is standardised, newer versions of the browser will drop the prefix, which is why you should always use the un-prefixed version of the style as well.

In the case of gradients, the syntax has been standardised for some time, so with *current* versions of virtually all the major browsers, you can use it without a prefix like so:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65) 0, transparent);
```

That should work just fine in the lastest version of all the main browsers, including Firefox and including Chrome.

So if you just want to support current browser versions, you don't even need the `-webkit-` prefix at all.

However, that's not always realistic, because you probably need to support *older* versions of some browsers.

In that case it helps to know which browser versions require a prefix, to help you decide whether to support them by providing the prefixed version of the style (because if you support them all it can be a lot of repetition in the CSS code with all those prefixes).

So, for example, a lot of Safari users might not be on the latest version, which means that they will need the `-webkit-` prefix. Or you might want to support Android devices, which also still need it.

But the good news is that Firefox hasn't needed a prefix for this feature for a long time, so you can safely drop the `-moz-` prefix.

A good place to find out about this sort of thing is at [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), which gives exact details about historic browser support for a load of browser features.

Hope that helps.