# Multiple CSS3 animation on the same element

Tags: css, animation

I have a little problem in here related with CSS3 animations.

I want to run animation and than run it again reversed. To make this I'm using:

```
-webkit-animation: moveKv 1s forwards, moveKv 1s forwards 2s reverse;
```

And that's how my keyframes looks like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'moveKv' {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

Everything works fine in Chrome canary, but it don't work in stable chrome. For some reason as soon as I add delay animation stops working.

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57dw8/)

**EDIT**: Okay, let me show you what I want eventually.
http://jsfiddle.net/57dw8/5/

**EDIT 2**: Actually the reason was pretty simple. Use 2 animations with same name wasn't supported in stable chrome at the moment post was created.

Comment: Do you eventually want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/57dw8/1/ ?

Comment: Well, more or less, but I need to control delay between initial and reversed animation without changing duration of actual animation. If we change this case a little bit I'll need this square to rotate with duration of 0.5s and have delay of 4s between animations. I'm not sure why delay breaks everything, everything works on my other animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the cleanest way, but since your animation is that simple: why not using two animations (one forward, one backward) with the same duration and apply 1T delay to the second one (to start from the end of the first) ?

<kbd>[Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/57dw8/7/)</kbd>

```
.wrap { position: relative; }

.banner {
    position      : absolute;
    top           : 0; 
    left          : 0;
    width         : 100px;
    height        : 100px;
    background    : #000;

    border-left   : 10px solid red;
    border-right  : 10px solid green;
    border-bottom : 10px solid blue;
    border-top    : 10px solid yellow;

    -webkit-animation : moveForward 1s, 1s moveBackward 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes 'moveForward' {
    0%   { -webkit-transform : rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform : rotate(180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes 'moveBackward' {
    0%   { -webkit-transform : rotate(180deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform : rotate(0deg); }
}
```

I've prefixed the code in the Fiddle with [Nettus Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php), so you can run it crossbrowser now.

Comment: Because I have 45 animation on that page, so it makes it 90 animation with "backwards" and + I need to write prefix for each of this. Though there might be other way instead of this.

Comment: For the prefixes, you don't have to write nothing: open the link I posted, paste all your CSS in that textarea and click `Prefixize` :) For the main problem instead, if you have a lot of animations, keep looking for an alternative solution :/

Comment: Yeah I've tried nettuts prefixr, but it works pretty bad with @keyframes.

Comment: You can also use a real-time prefixer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19904268/1654265 ;)

Comment: Also tried and also works pretty bad with keyframes. :) I've tried it 6 months ago tho, maybe something changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty bad" ? :|

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer....

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/57dw8/3/

```
.banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: moveKv infinite 2000ms;/*change here*/
    background: #000;
}


@-webkit-keyframes moveKv {
            0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
            50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
            100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        }
```

Comment: please change to 5000ms(or you can give value) instead of 2000ms...and want to animate property once time only you cant change to 1 instead of infinte...

Answer (score 0):

You should use two properties -

```
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
```

animation-direction - Configures whether or not the animation should alternate direction on each run through the sequence or reset to the start point and repeat itself.

animation-iteration-count - Configures the number of times the animation should repeat; you can specify infinite to repeat the animation indefinitely.

Must read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: I've managed to run animation twice using:
http://jsfiddle.net/57dw8/2/
But I need a delay now tho.

Comment: And I need that delay wasn't changing animation speed. So if my square rotates for .5s it should stay like that. So if I change animation duration to 10s, I want the 9s delay between two 0.5s animations.

Comment: animation-timing-function can be useful.